# VBA code error on pull or extract data from HTML website

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, getelementsbyclassname, navigateurl

I try to extract or pull data from HTML Element into Excel using VBA code:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_fGBlOLzMxmV3r-WwC8klcBNB7wUuJN2/view?usp=sharing

My idea is to extract and pull the exchange rate data in yellow highlight as from the HTML website:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LACA6quFz_Am6mGVjGQ39xvehtX1sybB/view?usp=sharing

Unfortunately, when i try to run the code, it compile the error as "run-time error 445" and "object doesn't support this action"

Appreciate someone can guide me to find out what is the error.
Below is my full VBA code:

```
Sub ExchangeRate()
Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
Dim htmlEleCollection As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim i As Integer

i = 1

Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
ieObj.Visible = True
ieObj.navigate "https://secure.mas.gov.sg/msb/ExchangeRatesFeed.aspx?currency=jpy"

While ieObj.readyState <> 4 Or ieObj.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

Set htmlEleCollection = ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("paditembox").Item(0).getElementsById("item").Value

For Each htmlEle In htmlEleCollection
    If htmlEle.Children.Length > 1 Then

       With ActiveSheet
           .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent
           .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(1).textContent
           .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(2).textContent
           .Range("D" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(3).textContent
           .Range("E" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(4).textContent
           .Range("F" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(5).textContent
           .Range("G" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(6).textContent
       End With
    End If

    i = i + 1

Next htmlEle
End Sub
```

New Regex VBA code as below:

```
Public Sub ExchangeRate()
    Dim results(), matches As Object, s As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://eservices.mas.gov.sg/api/action/datastore/search.json?resource_id=5aa64bc2-d234-43f3-892e-2f587a220f74&fields=end_of_week,usd_sgd,jpy_sgd_100&limit=1&sort=end_of_week%20desc", False
        .send
        s = .responseText
    End With
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False

        If .Pattern = "usd_sgd"":""(.*?)""" Then
           .MultiLine = True
           Set matches = .Execute(s)
           ReDim results(1 To matches.Count)

         ElseIf .Pattern = "jpy_sgd_100"":""(.*?)""" Then
            .MultiLine = True
            Set matches = .Execute(s)
            ReDim results(1 To matches.Count)
         End If

   End With
   Dim match As Variant, r As Long
   For Each match In matches
       r = r + 1
       results(r) = match.submatches(0)
   Next
   With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
       .Cells(2, 2).Resize(UBound(results), 1) = Application.Transpose(results)
       .Cells(2, 3).Resize(UBound(results), 1) = Application.Transpose(results)
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: what line is causing the error? can you post the complete error mesage?

Comment: "Run time error "424":Object require" on the line Set GetJSON = JSONConverter.ParseJson(.responseText).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, the following should fetch you the content you wanna grab from there.

```
Sub fetchData()
    Const Url = "https://secure.mas.gov.sg/msb/ExchangeRatesFeed.aspx?currency=jpy"
    Dim oItem As Object, Xdoc As New DOMDocument, R&

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .send
        Xdoc.LoadXML .responseText
    End With

    For Each oItem In Xdoc.getElementsByTagName("item")
        R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = oItem.getElementsByTagName("description")(0).Text
    Next oItem
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

This are the type of output the above script produces:

```
100 Japanese Yen buys 1.3006 Singapore Dollars
100 Japanese Yen buys 1.3001 Singapore Dollars
100 Japanese Yen buys 1.2986 Singapore Dollars
100 Japanese Yen buys 1.2887 Singapore Dollars
100 Japanese Yen buys 1.2857 Singapore Dollars
100 Japanese Yen buys 1.2726 Singapore Dollars
100 Japanese Yen buys 1.2773 Singapore Dollars
```

You can do string manipulation like:

```
For Each oItem In Xdoc.getElementsByTagName("item")
    R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = Split(Split(oItem.getElementsByTagName("description")(0).Text, "buys ")(1), " ")(0)
Next oItem
```

or apply regex to scoop out the desired portion from the above results.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had try your suggestion using regex:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V2GAnWCapJWs-x1eIMzQnTuWD83Ck1FT/view?usp=sharing. After run the code, the results is not really capture all the exchange rate as i want: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LU_1wEVhzh512NUAvWX-BBZof4erjbm7/view?usp=sharing. Appreciate if you could guide me on what went wrong for my code in order to capture the correct exchange rate in numberic only

Comment: This [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/stop-automatically-changing-numbers-to-dates-452bd2db-cc96-47d1-81e4-72cec11c4ed8?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) might help.

Comment: A quick and dirty hack would be `"'" & Split(Split(oItem.getElementsByTagName("description")(0).Text, "buys ")(1), " ")(0)`.

Comment: Pls kindly check out the my regex VBA code as above, i trying to use regex to scoop out the portion for exchange rate for usd_sgd & jpy_sgd_100 into same worksheet in cell B2 & C2.I try to use if else then statement for 2 different pattern "usd_sgd" and "jpy_sgd_100". After i run the code, it compile error "Run time error 424 object require" on line:For Each match In matches, appreciate you can assist me to find out what is this error mean for?

Comment: I'm done answering your questions. This is not how SO works. If you have different questions other than what you asked in the first place, create a new post describing your current issues. Btw, selecting the answer and then again deselecting the same is not a good practice. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenient caused. I will open new post if i have new question. I have learn so much from you, thank you very much for your kind support!